# subtract / change a "zero" number in ms sql: 1001 to 101

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a little problem: I need to change / subtract "0" from a number in ms sql,
a little example:

I got
1000008448
And it need to be: 100008448 on a whole table...

Anyone got a nice idea how to do it? ( Iam not skilled in MS SQL :( )

Edit:  More examples:

100323 would be 10323
10233 would be 1233
10000 would be 1000...

Comment: Is this number format standard ? Can 0 appear in other places?

Comment: what is you have record like this? 200800 ? what will be the result?

Comment: What about the condition where you have only one zero in number..?

Comment: Basic math is easy .. as long as you know the number format :)

Comment: Please try to edit your question and add a few more samples. Is it always that there's one leading non-zero digit, then a number of zeros, then a non-zero digit, then any number of digits? What are the edge cases here? Can there be numbers with no zeros in them?

Comment: I've seen you extended examples - so, there's always just one leading non-zero digit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following may do what you want (it "replaces" the most significant digits `x0` to `x`):

```
UPDATE table SET col=col
    -power(10, floor(log10(col)))*floor(col/power(10, floor(log10(col))))
    +power(10, floor(log10(col))-1)*floor(col/power(10, floor(log10(col))))
```

See [sqlFiddle :)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/279c5/2)

Comment: Good example, just cast it to some integer type because the result should be floating point. And the field to store it might be not.

Comment: CAST(COL-power(10, floor(log10(COL)))*0.9 AS INTEGER ) this was working, dont know why you changed it. BUT THANK YOU!

Comment: @Unomagan because the "`*0.9`" only works correctly if the first digits are `10` - the new version supports any digit so that all your new examples also work (e.g. "`200800` should be `20800`"). See the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/279c5/2) I posted.

Comment: @Lucero The new version did not work... 100008448  went to something like (cant remember) 108448 way to many zeros gone :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it a numeric field?  Are all your numbers 1000000000 numbers?

If so,

```
UPDATE table 
SET mycol = mycol - 900000000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update yourtable set
      yourcolumn=
        cast(stuff(cast(yourcolumn as varchar),
                    CHARINDEX('0',cast(yourcolumn as varchar)),1,'')
             as int)
      where CHARINDEX('0',cast(yourcolumn as varchar))>0
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for all of the examples you've posted so far. It's doing it as string manipulation, which I'd usually advise is best left to a better tool than SQL Server:

```
declare @T table (Frm int not null,Too int not null)
insert into @T (Frm,Too) values
(1001, 101),
(1000008448, 100008448),
(100323, 10323),
(10233, 1233),
(10000, 1000)

select
    CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(Frm,1,1) + SUBSTRING(Frm,3,20)) Frm,Too
from
    (select CONVERT(varchar(20),Frm) Frm,Too from @T) t
```

Result:

```
Frm         Too
----------- -----------
101         101
100008448   100008448
10323       10323
1233        1233
1000        1000
```

But no doubt there are more cases in your actual data that this doesn't work for.

Answer (score -1):

According to your initial phrasing of the problem, you would need the following SQL statement

```
update <table>
set <field> = 100008448
where <field> = 1000008448;
```

Of course, you would replace  with your tablename and  with the fieldname.

It may well be that you have not phrased the problem correctly as the above is an answer for a specific problem and not a general one.

Comment: that's not the OP wants. If the number is 1008, he wants it to be 108. Subtracting 1 zero fro the original data.

Comment: This is just silly. -1 for the answer. It was not a question on how to write an update.

Comment: I answered the question posed. If the OP wanted a more general answer, he should have posted a more general question!